# Operation has injection no error but is not included

Tags: operation, smartpy

My contract is [here](https://smartpy.io/demo/explore.html?address=KT18rxeQo6hcxMQHvhoWMEiSJrXYUSzCrBde)

[image]

===
[image]

===
but not include 
[image]

== 
What's wrong! Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send an operation, it first goes to the mempool, and only then bakers include it into the block. So there is some delay...

I highly recommend you use [tzkt.io](https://tzkt.io) explorer, because it also checks operations in the mempool so you will see them right after sending or if it's stuck in the mempool.

For example:

[image: TzKT - Tezos blockchain explorer]

Answer (score 0):

Something didn't work correctly. If you click on "Operations" tab on the SmartPy explorer, you can see there are only 2 operations. This is confirmed by [looking at tzstas](https://zeronet.tzstats.com/KT18rxeQo6hcxMQHvhoWMEiSJrXYUSzCrBde) and looking at [BCD](https://better-call.dev/zero/KT18rxeQo6hcxMQHvhoWMEiSJrXYUSzCrBde/operations)

I suggest you try again.

Comment: Sometimes bakers simply take a long time to bake on test networks. It's pretty common.

Comment: the operation always not broadcast in block

Answer (score 0):

You were looking at the wrong network on TzStats. It actually appears on zeronet - see [here](https://zeronet.tzstats.com/KT18rxeQo6hcxMQHvhoWMEiSJrXYUSzCrBde).